Coupon for new order
I have the following code:
// Initializing settings from the admin panel
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_coupon_settings_init');

function custom_coupon_settings_init() {
    // Saves settings for coupon generation
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_generation_delay');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_order_minimum');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_order_maximum');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_minimum_amount');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_maximum_amount'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_expiration_days');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_individual_use');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_usage_limit');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_email_restriction');
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_exclude_sale_items'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_usage_limit_per_user'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_allowed_products'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_excluded_products'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_allowed_categories'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_excluded_categories'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_discount_type'); 
    register_setting('custom_coupon_settings_group', 'coupon_discount_value'); 

    add_settings_section(
        'custom_coupon_main_section',
        'Coupon Settings',
        null,
        'coupon-settings'
    );

    // Adding existing fields
    add_settings_field('coupon_generation_delay', 'Coupon Generation Delay (minutes)', 'coupon_generation_delay_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_order_minimum', 'Order Minimum Amount', 'coupon_order_minimum_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_order_maximum', 'Order Maximum Amount', 'coupon_order_maximum_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_minimum_amount', 'Coupon Minimum Order Amount', 'coupon_minimum_amount_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_maximum_amount', 'Coupon Maximum Order Amount', 'coupon_maximum_amount_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_expiration_days', 'Coupon Expiration (days)', 'coupon_expiration_days_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_individual_use', 'Individual Use Only', 'coupon_individual_use_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_usage_limit', 'Coupon Usage Limit', 'coupon_usage_limit_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_usage_limit_per_user', 'Coupon Usage Limit per User', 'coupon_usage_limit_per_user_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_email_restriction', 'Restrict Coupon to Email', 'coupon_email_restriction_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_exclude_sale_items', 'Exclude Sale Items', 'coupon_exclude_sale_items_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_allowed_products', 'Allowed Products', 'coupon_allowed_products_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_excluded_products', 'Excluded Products', 'coupon_excluded_products_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_allowed_categories', 'Allowed Categories', 'coupon_allowed_categories_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 
    add_settings_field('coupon_excluded_categories', 'Excluded Categories', 'coupon_excluded_categories_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section'); 

    // New fields for discount type and value
    add_settings_field('coupon_discount_type', 'Discount Type', 'coupon_discount_type_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
    add_settings_field('coupon_discount_value', 'Discount Value', 'coupon_discount_value_callback', 'coupon-settings', 'custom_coupon_main_section');
}

function coupon_generation_delay_callback() {
    $delay = get_option('coupon_generation_delay', 10); 
    echo '<input type="number" name="coupon_generation_delay" value="' . esc_attr($delay) . '" />';
}

function coupon_order_minimum_callback() {
    $order_minimum = get_option('coupon_order_minimum', 300); 
    echo '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="coupon_order_minimum" value="' . esc_attr($order_minimum) . '" />';
}

function coupon_order_maximum_callback() {
    $order_maximum = get_option('coupon_order_maximum', 1000); 
    echo '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="coupon_order_maximum" value="' . esc_attr($order_maximum) . '" />';
}

function coupon_minimum_amount_callback() {
    $coupon_minimum = get_option('coupon_minimum_amount', 500); 
    echo '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="coupon_minimum_amount" value="' . esc_attr($coupon_minimum) . '" />';
}

function coupon_maximum_amount_callback() {
    $coupon_maximum = get_option('coupon_maximum_amount', 1000); 
    echo '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="coupon_maximum_amount" value="' . esc_attr($coupon_maximum) . '" />';
}

function coupon_expiration_days_callback() {
    $expiration_days = get_option('coupon_expiration_days', 14); 
    echo '<input type="number" name="coupon_expiration_days" value="' . esc_attr($expiration_days) . '" />';
}

function coupon_individual_use_callback() {
    $individual_use = get_option('coupon_individual_use', 'yes');
    echo '<select name="coupon_individual_use">
            <option value="yes" ' . selected($individual_use, 'yes', false) . '>Yes</option>
            <option value="no" ' . selected($individual_use, 'no', false) . '>No</option>
          </select>';
}

function coupon_usage_limit_callback() {
    $usage_limit = get_option('coupon_usage_limit', 1); 
    echo '<input type="number" name="coupon_usage_limit" value="' . esc_attr($usage_limit) . '" />';
}

function coupon_usage_limit_per_user_callback() {
    $usage_limit_per_user = get_option('coupon_usage_limit_per_user', 1); 
    echo '<input type="number" name="coupon_usage_limit_per_user" value="' . esc_attr($usage_limit_per_user) . '" />';
}

function coupon_email_restriction_callback() {
    $email_restriction = get_option('coupon_email_restriction', 'yes');
    echo '<select name="coupon_email_restriction">
            <option value="yes" ' . selected($email_restriction, 'yes', false) . '>Yes</option>
            <option value="no" ' . selected($email_restriction, 'no', false) . '>No</option>
          </select>';
}

function coupon_exclude_sale_items_callback() {
    $exclude_sale_items = get_option('coupon_exclude_sale_items', 'yes');
    echo '<select name="coupon_exclude_sale_items">
            <option value="yes" ' . selected($exclude_sale_items, 'yes', false) . '>Yes</option>
            <option value="no" ' . selected($exclude_sale_items, 'no', false) . '>No</option>
          </select>';
}

function coupon_allowed_products_callback() {
    $allowed_products = get_option('coupon_allowed_products', '');
    echo '<input type="text" name="coupon_allowed_products" value="' . esc_attr($allowed_products) . '" placeholder="Product IDs, comma-separated" />';
}

function coupon_excluded_products_callback() {
    $excluded_products = get_option('coupon_excluded_products', '');
    echo '<input type="text" name="coupon_excluded_products" value="' . esc_attr($excluded_products) . '" placeholder="Product IDs, comma-separated" />';
}

function coupon_allowed_categories_callback() {
    $allowed_categories = get_option('coupon_allowed_categories', '');
    echo '<input type="text" name="coupon_allowed_categories" value="' . esc_attr($allowed_categories) . '" placeholder="Category IDs, comma-separated" />';
}

function coupon_excluded_categories_callback() {
    $excluded_categories = get_option('coupon_excluded_categories', '');
    echo '<input type="text" name="coupon_excluded_categories" value="' . esc_attr($excluded_categories) . '" placeholder="Category IDs, comma-separated" />';
}

function coupon_discount_type_callback() {
    $discount_type = get_option('coupon_discount_type', 'fixed_cart');
    echo '<select name="coupon_discount_type">
            <option value="fixed_cart" ' . selected($discount_type, 'fixed_cart', false) . '>Fixed Cart</option>
            <option value="percent" ' . selected($discount_type, 'percent', false) . '>Percentage</option>
            <option value="percent_coupon" ' . selected($discount_type, 'percent_coupon', false) . '>Percentage on Coupon</option>
          </select>';
}

function coupon_discount_value_callback() {
    $discount_value = get_option('coupon_discount_value', 10); // 10% sau 10 lei implicit
    echo '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="coupon_discount_value" value="' . esc_attr($discount_value) . '" />';
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_coupon_settings_menu');

function custom_coupon_settings_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Coupon Settings', 
        'Coupon Settings', 
        'manage_options', 
        'coupon-settings', 
        'custom_coupon_settings_page', 
        'dashicons-tickets-alt', 
        75
    );
}

function custom_coupon_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Coupon Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
            settings_fields('custom_coupon_settings_group');
            do_settings_sections('coupon-settings');
            submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Function for generating a unique voucher code
function generate_unique_voucher_code() {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $coupon_code = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $coupon_code .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $coupon_code;
}

// Function to schedule the generation of a promotional code at checkout
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'schedule_coupon_creation', 10, 2);
function schedule_coupon_creation($order_id, $order) {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('generate_coupon_event', array($order_id))) {
        $delay = get_option('coupon_generation_delay', 10); 
        wp_schedule_single_event(strtotime('+' . $delay . ' minutes'), 'generate_coupon_event', array($order_id));
    }
}

// Function to delete a coupon generated when the order status is no longer "Completed"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'delete_coupon_on_order_status_change', 10, 4);
function delete_coupon_on_order_status_change($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order) {
    if ($old_status === 'completed' && $new_status !== 'completed') {
        $coupon_code = get_post_meta($order_id, '_generated_coupon_code', true);
        if ($coupon_code) {
            $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
            $coupon->delete(true);
            delete_post_meta($order_id, '_coupon_generated');
            delete_post_meta($order_id, '_generated_coupon_code');
        }
    }
}

// The function to generate the coupon
add_action('generate_coupon_event', 'custom_promo_code_creation');
function custom_promo_code_creation($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order && $order->get_status() === 'completed') {
        if (get_post_meta($order_id, '_coupon_generated', true)) {
            return;
        }

        $order_subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();

        $order_minimum = get_option('coupon_order_minimum', 300);
        $order_maximum = get_option('coupon_order_maximum', 1000);

        if ($order_subtotal >= $order_minimum && $order_subtotal <= $order_maximum) {
            $coupon_code = generate_unique_voucher_code();
            
            $discount_type = get_option('coupon_discount_type', 'fixed_cart');
            $discount_value = get_option('coupon_discount_value', 10);

            $discount_amount = 0;
            if ($discount_type === 'percent') {
                // Calculates the fixed amount of the discount based on the percentage
                $discount_amount = $order_subtotal * ($discount_value / 100);
                $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; 
            } elseif ($discount_type === 'fixed_cart') {
                $discount_amount = $discount_value;
            } elseif ($discount_type === 'percent_coupon') {
                $discount_amount = $discount_value; 
                $discount_type = 'percent';
            }

            $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
            if ($coupon instanceof WC_Coupon) {
                $coupon->set_code($coupon_code);
                $coupon->set_status('publish');
                $coupon->set_amount($discount_amount);
                $coupon->set_discount_type($discount_type);
                $coupon->set_description(sprintf(__('Generated coupon code from order #%s'), $order_id));

                $individual_use = get_option('coupon_individual_use', 'yes') === 'yes';
                $coupon->set_individual_use($individual_use);

                $usage_limit = get_option('coupon_usage_limit', 1);
                $coupon->set_usage_limit($usage_limit);

                $min_order_value = get_option('coupon_minimum_amount', 500);
                $coupon->set_minimum_amount($min_order_value);

                $expiration_days = get_option('coupon_expiration_days', 14);
                $expiration_date = strtotime('+' . $expiration_days . ' days');
                $coupon->set_date_expires($expiration_date);

                $coupon_maximum = get_option('coupon_maximum_amount', 1000);
                $coupon->set_maximum_amount($coupon_maximum);

                $exclude_sale_items = get_option('coupon_exclude_sale_items', 'yes') === 'yes';
                $coupon->set_exclude_sale_items($exclude_sale_items);

                $products_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', get_option('coupon_allowed_products', '')));
                $coupon->set_product_ids($products_ids);

                $excluded_products_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', get_option('coupon_excluded_products', '')));
                $coupon->set_excluded_product_ids($excluded_products_ids);

                $categories_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', get_option('coupon_allowed_categories', '')));
                $coupon->set_product_categories($categories_ids);

                $excluded_categories_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', get_option('coupon_excluded_categories', '')));
                $coupon->set_excluded_product_categories($excluded_categories_ids);

                $email_restriction = get_option('coupon_email_restriction', 'yes') === 'yes';
                if ($email_restriction) {
                    $allowed_email = $order->get_billing_email();
                    $coupon->add_meta_data('customer_email', array($allowed_email), true);
                }

                $coupon->save();

                update_post_meta($order_id, '_coupon_generated', true);
                update_post_meta($order_id, '_generated_coupon_code', $coupon_code);

                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();

                $to = $order->get_billing_email();
                $subject = sprintf(__('Your discount coupon from our store for order #%s'), $order_id);

                // We check the type of discount for the email
                if (get_option('coupon_discount_type', 'fixed_cart') === 'percent_coupon') {
                    $message = sprintf(__('Thank you for your order. Here are the details of your discount coupon for your next purchase:
<br><br>
<strong>Coupon Code:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Discount Amount:</strong> %s%%<br>
<strong>Discount Type:</strong> Percentage<br>
<strong>Expiration Date:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Number of Uses:</strong> %d<br>
<strong>Minimum Order Value:</strong> %s %s<br>
<strong>Maximum Coupon Value:</strong> %s %s<br>
<strong>Exclude Sale Items:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Products:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Excluded Products:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Categories:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Excluded Categories:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Email:</strong> %s<br>
<br>
The coupon is valid until %s and can be applied to orders over %s %s but not exceeding %s %s.'), 
                    $coupon_code, $discount_value, date('Y-m-d', $expiration_date), $usage_limit, $min_order_value, $currency, $coupon_maximum, $currency, $exclude_sale_items ? __('Yes') : __('No'), implode(', ', $products_ids), implode(', ', $excluded_products_ids), implode(', ', $categories_ids), implode(', ', $excluded_categories_ids),
                    $to, date('Y-m-d', $expiration_date), $min_order_value, $currency, $coupon_maximum, $currency);
                } else {
                    $message = sprintf(__('Thank you for your order. Here are the details of your discount coupon for your next purchase:
<br><br>
<strong>Coupon Code:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Discount Amount:</strong> %.2f %s<br>
<strong>Discount Type:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Expiration Date:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Number of Uses:</strong> %d<br>
<strong>Minimum Order Value:</strong> %s %s<br>
<strong>Maximum Coupon Value:</strong> %s %s<br>
<strong>Exclude Sale Items:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Products:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Excluded Products:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Categories:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Excluded Categories:</strong> %s<br>
<strong>Allowed Email:</strong> %s<br>
<br>
The coupon is valid until %s and can be applied to orders over %s %s but not exceeding %s %s.'), 
                    $coupon_code, $discount_amount, $currency, $discount_type === 'fixed_cart' ? __('Fixed Cart') : __('Percentage'), date('Y-m-d', $expiration_date), $usage_limit, $min_order_value, $currency, $coupon_maximum, $currency, $exclude_sale_items ? __('Yes') : __('No'), implode(', ', $products_ids), implode(', ', $excluded_products_ids), implode(', ', $categories_ids), implode(', ', $excluded_categories_ids),
                    $to, date('Y-m-d', $expiration_date), $min_order_value, $currency, $coupon_maximum, $currency);
                }

                $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

                wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }
        }
    }
}



The code allows the generation of a discount coupon at the end of the order (after a certain time set by me). Everything works correctly (all restrictions are configured correctly, clients are notified by email...).
How can I make the customers receive by email the names of the products and product categories that are set as restrictions in the coupon with a link to them. My code sends the IDs of the products and categories (and without a link) and the clients do not know which products/categories of products are accepted and which are not accepted.
How it looks now:
Allowed Products: 580, 574
Excluded Products: 568, 562
Allowed Categories: 40
Excluded Categories: 42
How I want it to look:
Allowed Products: Samsung Galaxy S24, Samsung Galaxy S24 (+link to their pages)
Excluded Products: Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max, Huawei Nova 12i, (+link to their pages)
Allowed Categories: phone (+link to their pages)
Excluded Categories: Tv (+link to their pages)
I tried to add the following code, but even so it only sends the ids:
function get_titles_from_ids($ids, $taxonomy = 'product') {
    $titles = array();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if ($taxonomy === 'product') {
            $product = wc_get_product($id);
            if ($product) {
                $titles[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a>';
            }
        } elseif ($taxonomy === 'product_cat') {
            $term = get_term($id, 'product_cat');
            if ($term && !is_wp_error($term)) {
                $titles[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $titles;
}


Please help me make it functional!
Thank you in advance!

Strange, your last function should work… Can you show how, and where, do you use it in your code?

Wouldn't it be easier to just create a specific page that lists which products & product categories are restricted, then have the link to that page in your email's copy? That way if you/your client ever need(s) to change what is restricted and what isn't you can just update that page. And customers will always find up-to-date information there vs an email that they potentially received some time ago.

Did you hook the last code into the order completed email template? Or wherever you want this to show?

@LoicTheAztec  I add the second code right at the end of the first code.

@brc Sorry, but I don't see the usage of get_titles_from_ids function in your main code. Can you show how you are using get_titles_from_ids in your main code, updating your question? Now note that you should not use anymore WordPress post meta functions with Orders, as you are losing the compatibility with High-Performance Order Storage, that is enabled by default since WooCommerce 8.2. You should use $order->get_meta('meta_key'); or $order->update_meta_data('meta_key', $value); (with $order->save();)…
